# What are the following keyboard shortcuts in a terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I am trying to figure out a few keyboard shortcuts in a terminal in Mac OS X (and Linux):

In the command line:

1. go to the next word
2. go to the previous word
3. go to the end of the line
4. go to the beginning of the line

This will make it easier to change commands. Right now, I am using the left/right arrow keys, which is time consuming.

EDIT: I used `bind -p` as suggested below. What do the following key bindings mean?

```
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\eb": backward-word
```

and:

```
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\ef": forward-word
```

Comment: Running `bind -p` should tell you what keyboard commands exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the readline [movement commands](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gdb-5.0/html_node/readline_6.html). They are shared with emacs. Here are the defaults:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: start of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: end of line
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: forward a word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>: backward a word

You might also have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> keys bound for back and forward a word. My OSX 10.6 doesn't, but my Ubuntu 12.04 does.

Note that in OSX you can't use alt by default since that puts in an accented letter. Rather, use escape. You have to hit it each time though, you can't hold it down.

The other answer referring to vi-mode may also be useful to you if you are familiar with vi. See [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/) for some more info.

Comment: also usefull `Ctrl-w` - delete prev word,

Comment: alt-f and alt-b don't work for me here... any ideas?

Comment: read the above answer, carefully. works fine on Linux debian

Comment: As @wuxmedia said, read carefully. Alt doesn't work normally on OSX.

Comment: You can use ⌥B and ⌥F in Terminal if you check Settings > Keyboard > Use option as meta key.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VI mode command-line editing, then you would use (in order) `w b $ 0`

Comment: I am not talking about vi, but regular command-line in the terminal, or did you mean something else?

Comment: @kloop Some shells have a vi mode; try `set -o vi` and see if the input now behaves like that most delicious of editors.